# How do we select the student who takes all classes taught by Davidson and how to select all the teacher's name who teaches atleast 3 classes?

Tags: mysql, database

all! I'm taking database class and have couple of questions that is so confusing to me. down below is my table

```
Student(S_ID, S_FIRST_NAME, S_LAST_NAME, S_MAJOR)

Course(C_ID, C_NAME, C_INST_NAME, C_ROOM)

takes(S_ID,C_ID)
```

Q-1.i want to select all the student_id who takes all courses taught by Davidson. I tried with this code

```
select s.S_ID from student s inner join (select t.S_ID from takes t inner join
course c on t.C_ID = c.C_ID group by t.S_ID having sum(case when c.C_INST_NAME
= 'Davidson' then 1 else 0 end) = 3) t on s.S_ID = t.S_ID;
```

it works because i know how many classes Davidson teaches(in my case 3). how do we write the query if we don't know how many classes he teaches?

Q-2. i want to select all the instructors who teach atleast 3 classes. For this question i did following

```
select distinct C_INST_NAME from course where C_ID >= 3;
+-------------+
| C_INST_NAME |
+-------------+
| Peterson    |
| Davidson    |
| Jackson     |
| Hanney      |
+-------------+
```

But i got all the instructor, any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -2):

Q1.

```
SELECT
   S_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(C_ID ORDER BY C_ID ASC)
FROM
   takes
WHERE
   GROUP_CONCAT(C_ID ORDER BY C_ID ASC) = (    
   SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(Course.C_ID ORDER BY C_ID ASC)
   FROM
       Course
   WHERE
       Course.C_INST_NAME = "Davidson"
)
GROUP BY
   S_ID
```

Q2.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(C_ID) AS "numClassesTaught", Course.C_INST_NAME
FROM
   Course
GROUP BY
   Course.C_INST_NAME
HAVING
    numClassesTaught >= 3
```

Those should both work.

Comment: Q1 answer definitely doesn't fit the brief. For Q2 answer, plainly, you're selecting the wrong thing.

Comment: @user2278120 for the question-1,  provided code gives me the student even they only have one class with Davidson, I wanted the students who takes all classes from Davidson. And, second code gives me '0' output.

Comment: @Anonymous  Try my answer for q1 and q2 now.

Comment: @user2278120 Q-2 worked perfectly but Q-1 gives me empty set, Still trying to figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: @Anonymous  how about that?

Comment: Got the error: 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.